# How to make elements in a div clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm making a search engine program. People can enter a question and it will be displayed in a list in another `div` (the `stackdisplay`).

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" id="qInput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="ques(); stackDisplay()">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="stack">
    <span id="stackDisplay">
        <center><b><u> LIST OF QUESTIONS</u></b></center>
        <button id="close" onmouseover="clo()"> &times; </button>
    </span>
    <button onmouseover="list()"> &#9776; </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function ques()
{
    var question = document.getElementById("qInput").value;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*1200);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*580);
    c.fillText(question, x, y);
}

var i =1;
function stackDisplay()
{
    var quest = document.getElementById("qInput").value;
    document.getElementById("stackDisplay").innerHTML += i+") "+quest+"<br>";
    i+=1;
}
```

I can't use `addeventlistener` or `onclick` function in javascript because it makes the whole div clickable when I only want the questions listed to be clickable. Is there a way to do this? I want to make another div to pop up when clicking the questions.

Comment: You're adding text and a `<br>` but you should use a separate element for each question and make *that* clickable.

Comment: Do not play with html in a string if you want to use JS and do not want to break whole page... Use DOM instead like document.createElement(tagName) someElement.appendChild(newCreated), etc.